# OpenFlow: how to set the frame to show properly in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, coverflow

I'm trying to use the AFOpenFlowView in landscape mode, but I get a black stripe as if the frame was set not go over the status bar or, better, not over the frame where the status bar is in portrait mode.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

AFOpenFlowView *af = [[AFOpenFlowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, applicationFrame.size.height, applicationFrame.size.width)];
[af setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

NSString *imageName;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"picture_%d.png", i];
    [af setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
    [imageName release];
}

[af setNumberOfImages:9];
[af setViewDelegate:self];

[self setView:af];
[af release];
```

Here's an image to show what happens: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm extremely sorry for taking your time. At the end I found out what the solution was: I was initializing the window with the application frame, i.e.

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

instead of using the right code

```
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `applicationFrame.size.height` will give you the height minus the status bar.
It does no take in consideration that your phone is in landscape mode.

Just add the size as 480 x 300.

Can you try the following debug statement:

```
NSLog(@"Af frame: &@", NSStringFromCGRect(af.frame));
NSLog(@"Application frame: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(applicationFrame));
```

Comment: I don't think so... CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; I'm getting the bounds and not the applicationFrame.

Comment: Sorry read over that line, but it does look like blackbar is the same space as the statusbar.

Comment: Yes it does look like the black space is the same as the statusbar. Even if I set the frame as 480x300 it doesn't work. I get the same result: a black stripe on the right.

Comment: Af frame: {{0, 0}, {480, 320}}
Application frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
This is what I get on the console... Not encouraging though
Thank you for you time anyway

Comment: So the error is in the render code of AFOpenFlowView , try making it 500.

Comment: Not working... 
Af frame: {{0, 0}, {580, 320}}
Application frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
I will try to start everything from zero again... I'll let you know

Comment: I created a new project and I did everything from the beginning. Guess what? It's working! I don't know what was wrong with the last project and I'm sorry for taking your time. I was going mad to solve this problem but now it's working. Thank you anyway :)